React MUI 5 unable to overwrite default styles with custom-defined styles
I am trying to overwrite default MUI 5 Button styles with custom styles (using either withStyles or through a className (defined using makeStyles), but the default styles are always on top of the custom ones. The issue with withStyles was resolved by adding those styles to the global style overrides when defining the theme, but the className-based ones are problematic.
How do I resolve that? Below are some screenshots of the weird behavior.
Edit: The style file used to define the custom styles:
import { Theme } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';

const BTN_WIDTH = 160;
const BTN_MIN_HEIGHT = 34;

export default makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  btn: {
    width: BTN_WIDTH,
    minHeight: BTN_MIN_HEIGHT,
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
    paddingRight: theme.spacing(2),
  }
}));


^ A screenshot of the styles of the button in question. (Some default styles were removed to fit in one screenshot). You can see the default styles overwriting the paddings set by the custom styles.

Indeed, your class is getting overridden because it has same specificity as the MUI classes. Here you have 3 choices.

Invert imports: Your class is getting overridden because it has same specificity and is imported AFTER MUI import. This may be the hardest to put in place as import are sometimes hard to manage.

Make everything in your class !important (e.g: width: 100px !important). This is pretty dirty and i would not recommand doing so.

Use specificity to your advantage and apply a higher-specificity class.
Here, you could use a css rule like this:




div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.custom-div {
  background: red;
}

.important-div {
  background: black;
}

.important-div#very-important {
  background: green;
}
<div class="custom-div important-div" id="very-important"/>


In this exemple, even though background is defined everywhere, the rule with higher specificity wins (e.g: the one with an id).

I am using typescript-based style definitions, so no .css file imports are used. That's also why point 3 won't work, because the styles are always bound to a single class

I added an example of the file I use to define the styles.  @Symtox
